# Pc case instructions say screws for Psu should have come with Psu but it says the opposite

Tags: power-supply, desktop

Basically, I'm building a Pc and all I have bought so far is the MOBO, the Psu and the case. Im trying to assemble it in an order that I can see if a part isn't working and return if not because I can't afford the whole thing so far. I am wondering what to do when the instructions for my case (corsair spec 01) say that I should install the psu(evga 500w) with the screws that came with it. But the Psu is telling me that the case should have them. What should I do? And also, I tried plugging in the Psu to test it without plugging any of the leads in to anything, and I think it powered on but the fan didn't turn on. Should it have?

Comment: They don't normally come with the PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any computer shop, they'll cost you 50p. They're one size fits all.

Comment: There's actually a couple of different screws (UTS and metric), but the PSU mountring screws are 6-32 thread.  If you aren't close to a computer store, you should be able to find these at any hardware store, or online.

Comment: @fixer1234 I've never heard of UTS, but a quick Google tells me why - it's a US standard, not international. Thanks for the info, though - appreciated.

Comment: We don't care what the rest of the world does.  The only way we'll go metric is if we're dragged there kicking and screaming.  :-)

Comment: Friend of mine once called it 'the biggest island in the world'.